# Fragment overlay ActionBar and missing content in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I could not solve this problem.
[image]

Here my `Main activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, AttendanceFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, R.string.nav_drawer_open, R.string.nav_drawer_close);

    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    showAttendanceFragment();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_drawer, menu);
    return true;
}
private void showAttendanceFragment() {
    AttendanceFragment fragment = new AttendanceFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}


@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
```

}

Here the `main xlm`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:background="@color/primary">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/accent"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/accent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:background="@color/primary"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `bar`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primary_darker"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and the `fragment`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hoangdang.diemdanh.Fragments.AttendanceFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I tried use `linear layout` but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand the `DrawerLayout`. You can check this here: [Google DrawerLayout Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). As the note from Google Guide:

> The main content view (the FrameLayout above) must be the first child in the DrawerLayout because the XML order implies z-ordering and the drawer must be on top of the content.
>
> The main content view is set to match the parent view's width and height, because it represents the entire UI when the navigation drawer is hidden.
>
> The drawer view (the ListView) must specify its horizontal gravity with the android:layout_gravity attribute. To support right-to-left (RTL) languages, specify the value with "start" instead of "left" (so the drawer appears on the right when the layout is RTL).
>
> The drawer view specifies its width in dp units and the height matches the parent view. The drawer width should be no more than 320dp so the user can always see a portion of the main content.

As we can see in your `xml`:

1. your main content view is `AppBar`, that's not good.
2. Both `AppBar` and `FrameLayout` have `match_parent` in `layoutParams`, that's the reason why you got the issue.

So, how to solve it? you have to combine AppBar and FrameLayout under 1 view only (Relative or LinearLayout) and put it as the first child of `DrawerLayout`

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Remove your `FrameLayout` from `activity_main.xml` and place it to `app_bar_main.xml` under `AppBarLayout`.

**2.** Remove `attribute android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` from `FrameLayout`
**2.** Add attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to `FrameLayout`.

**Update your `activity_main.xml` as below:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:background="@color/primary">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/accent"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/accent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:background="@color/primary"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Update `app_bar_main.xml` as below:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primary_darker"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Content :: Fragments-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope this will work~

Comment: If my answer helps to resolve your problem then you should mark it as right answer.

Comment: i already marked other answer because he explained in detail not only the code

Answer (score 0):

Add layout behavior and try...

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: thanks for response, but this is just a part of the solution, you can check for explanation and code example for @FAT and Kingfisher Phuoc answers